# Is there a way to override system name for Java app?

Tags: java, linux, windows, ubuntu, icedtea

There is a Java Web Start application that I'm trying to run under Java on Linux. I'm using `icedtea-netx` on Ubuntu Linux.  When I try to run the application, it starts up, shows the splash screen, then produces an error saying:

> "Currently the application only supports the following system: Windows".

So I'm wondering, is there a way to set your system information in Java to pretend that it’s Windows?  I understand that this program might really require some aspect of Windows, but I'd like to try anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Try to run it with an argument like `-Dos.name=Windows`, but it actually depends on how the system information is acquired in the app. If it's authors were "smart" enough, they might be determining the OS even by the file separator.

Comment: Probably not, you could fool around with `-Dos.name` but you may well break Java internals doing that. You could try running a Windows JRE in Wine (or Windows in a virtual machine).

Comment: Maybe I'm not using that option right. I just ran javaws -Dos.name=Windows webstart.do and it returns "netx: Invalid argument: net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.optionparser.InvalidArgumentException: [-Dos.name=Windows, webstart.do]"

Comment: I tried using wine to run Java for windows, but apparently the latest versions don't work anymore.  I tried using an earlier version and couldn't figure out how to pass the arguments yet.  Having to run a virtual machine for this is annoying.

Comment: The other thing that is annoying is people writing java programs that only run on Windows. The whole damn point of java was that it was universal.